# uninitialized constant Syke::Core RubyGem

Tags: ruby

I am building a RubyGem to generate test data and am running into an issue while building it. I have the main `syke.rb` file that was genereated from the initial gem build.

```
require "syke/version"
require "syke/internet"

mydir = __dir__

require 'i18n'

I18n.load_path += Dir[File.join(mydir, 'locales', '**/*.yml')]
I18n.available_locales = [:en]

module Syke
  class Core
    class << self
      def get(key)
        I18n.t("syke.#{key}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to pull values from a `.yml` file so in my `internet.rb` file I have this:

```
module Syke
  class Internet < Core
    class << self
      def email
        get('internet.domain')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am currently getting this error while trying to test the application with rspec:

> NameError: uninitialized constant Syke::Core

I have the internet class inheriting the Core class under the Syke module so I am confused why I would be getting this error message. Anybody have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `require "syke/internet"` is *before* you've defined `Syke::Core`.

Personally, I would move the definition of `Syke::Core` into it's own file that you can require inside either the main `syke.rb` (before requiring internet) file or in the `internet.rb` file itself.